# Order of accuracy of $0$

Tags: truncation-error

I had to calculate the truncation error, but the error gave me $0$. Then the question asked what is the order of accuracy, however since the error is $0$ should it be infinity?

---

We use this difference formula:

$$Q(h) = \frac{f(x-2h) - 8f(x-h) + 8f(x+h) -f(x+2h)}{12h}$$

And with the following Taylor expansions around $x$:

$\begin{align}
f(x-2h) &= f(x) - 2hf'(x) + 2h^2f''(x) - \frac{4}{3}h^3f'''(x) + \mathcal{O}(h^4)\\
f(x-h) &= f(x) - hf'(x) + \frac{1}{2}h^2f''(x) - \frac{1}{6}h^3f'''(x) + \mathcal{O}(h^4)\\
f(x-h) &= f(x) + hf'(x) + \frac{1}{2}h^2f''(x) + \frac{1}{6}h^3f'''(x) + \mathcal{O}(h^4)\\
f(x+2h) &= f(x) + 2hf'(x) + 2h^2f''(x) + \frac{4}{3}h^3f'''(x) + \mathcal{O}(h^4)\\
\end{align}$

Then we find the truncation error:

$\begin{align}
|f'(x) - Q(h)| &= |f'(x) - f(x)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{12h}-\frac{8}{12h}+\frac{8}{12h}-\frac{1}{12h}\right)\\
&- f'(x)\cdot\left(-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{6}\right)\\
&- f''(x)\cdot\left(\frac{h}{6}-\frac{h}{3}+\frac{h}{3}-\frac{h}{6}\right)\\
&- f'''(x)\cdot\left(-\frac{h^2}{9}+\frac{h^2}{9}+\frac{h^2}{9}-\frac{h^2}{9}\right)|
\end{align}$

As you can see, all the orders cancel out except for the first derivative

Therefore $|f'(x) - Q(h)| = |f'(x) - f'(x)| = 0$

Comment: If the error is actually $0$, then $\infty$ seems a reasonable choice for the order of accuracy.

Comment: Could you  please  share exactly what you've been doing? It usually doesn't make sense  for a truncation error to be $0$. If you were to truncate for example the Taylor series of $x^2$  at order $3$, than this error is indeed zero, but we can agree that it doesn't make much sense to do so.

Comment: @GáborPálovics I updated the question to show what I did

Comment: Your approximation of the derivative was construted in a manner that your error would be of order $h^5$. Your truncation error comes from the the things you are considering to be negligible: $\mathcal{O}(h^4)$. You should estimate those terms and give an upperbound which would be your truncation error.

Comment: Oh okay, I thought it would be true for the rest of the terms so I did not calculate the rest since we do not usually need to get to order 5. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cancel the orders out. Remember that each Taylor expansion has an error of $\frac{h^4}{24} f^{(4)}(\eta_i)$, and $\eta_i$ might vary for each case.

Comment: Yeah I calculated order 4 and they also cancelled out so I gave up thinking that the rest would cancel out. Gave up too soon!

Comment: It is a normal mistake to make, but since $\eta_i$ is just some number in the interval between x and the limit of your Taylor expansion, $\eta_1 \in [x-2h, x]$, $\eta_2 \in [x-h, x]$, and so on, $f^{(4)}(\eta_i)$ is likely different in each case. Therefore, $\mathcal{O}$ can't usually be cancelled, unless you continue the expansion. I'm glad this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Although having no error means that the accuracy is maximum, I would personally use a more elegant way of measuring accuracy, because infinity means that the scale of real numbers until there is all available for accuracies. As in, 200...10^5, etc.

Perhaps, use 100% (much more clear and easy to write and process).

Another option, of you want to see it as "efficiency", make it 1.

If you want to be *fine*, use **complete** accuracy.